# Rolling weighted average (or similar) filling for missing pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation, weighted-average

I've got pandas dataframe with values "along path", with distances, but some of the values are missing.
Dataframe looks like this:

```
    Idx AccumDist   ValT
0   1   3059    112
1   2   4281    194
2   3   4947    NaN
3   4   5460    NaN
4   5   5811    543
5   6   6021    591
6   7   6289    NaN
7   8   7487    909
8   9   8031    954
9   10  8242    1069
```

`AccumDist` and `ValT` is accumulated data, and some of the `ValT` are "missing".
What I want to do is to replace NaN in column `ValT` with averages to from closest "known" data in this column, weighted by `AccumDist` difference.

Because there could be missing `ValT` value after another (might be more than 1) I can't use rolling weighted average (or I don't know how to use it), while I still want to average only "closest known" values.

I was thinking about using `df.shift()`, maybe on some dataframe subset(s), but I'm not really sure how to do it. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `interpolate` based on the accumulated distance. Set that as the index and use `method='index'`. Then assign this calculation back to your DataFrame using the like-sized numpy array.

```
df['ValT_filled'] = df.set_index('AccumDist')['ValT'].interpolate(method='index').to_numpy()

#   Idx  AccumDist    ValT  ValT_filled
#0    1       3059   112.0   112.000000
#1    2       4281   194.0   194.000000
#2    3       4947     NaN   345.917647
#3    4       5460     NaN   462.935294
#4    5       5811   543.0   543.000000
#5    6       6021   591.0   591.000000
#6    7       6289     NaN   649.133697
#7    8       7487   909.0   909.000000
#8    9       8031   954.0   954.000000
#9   10       8242  1069.0  1069.000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much, perfect, clean, fast and easy solution. I never used many of such methods and I overcomplicate thigs trying by using workarounds (rolling weighted average...)